# Simple Clojure and CouchDB example for web app

Tags: clojure, couchdb

I want to experiment writing a web app with Clojure and CouchDB, but I can't find many examples to help me get started. Searching around the web a bit I see that I could use this combination of libraries:

- https://leiningen.org/
- http://www.luminusweb.net/
- https://github.com/clojure-clutch/clutch

The first two seem popular, but what about clutch, it doesn't look actively developed -- is it a good choice?

Assuming I use clutch, I'm struggling to find much example code, this seems to work, but is it the right approach?

Project creation:

```
lein new luminus couchdb-test
```

Add this in `project.clj` in `:dependencies`:

```
[com.ashafa/clutch "0.4.0"]
```

Run project:

```
lein run
```

And then in the REPL:

```
(require ['com.ashafa.clutch :as 'clutch])

;; Test connection to DB - I've created one called wiki
(clutch/get-database "wiki")

;; Get a list of all documents
(clutch/with-db "wiki"
    (clutch/all-documents))

;; Output all docs with contents
(clutch/with-db "wiki"
    (clutch/all-documents {:include_docs true}))

;; Output titles of all docs that have one
(map (fn [result] (:title (:doc result)))
            (clutch/with-db "wiki"
    (clutch/all-documents {:include_docs true})))
```

Any corrections, hints, or pointers to better examples would be great.

Comment: Here's where I've got to so far: https://github.com/ericclack/clojure-wiki -- any comments or pointers appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for this, Eric. I looked at your github example but can't get it to work, probably because of not properly configuring the profiles.clj file. Might you be able to clarify the ReadMe to give more specific instructions on adding credentials? Thx!

Comment: Hi Jessie, what error did you see and at which step of the instructions? Let me know and I'll update the README to make things easier to follow.

Comment: You could also run this and post the output: ```curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/_all_dbs```